# Loop into Array of Objects comparing two arrays - PUG (Jade)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, pug

I am trying in Javascript, using PUG template (if possible), to compare two arrays and when I find a correspondance in IDs, display some particular elements.

```
// First Array : I iterate over "hearts" object 
// Called in PUG : - const user

    [
      {
        "hearts": [
          "5e70c63a94b27b164c9b897f",
          "5e723c75e4bfdf4f58c55e32"
        ],
        "_id": "5e6bb1189978fd5afc98c57a",
        "email": "catherine@catherine.com",
        "name": "Catherine",
        "photo": "0121b7fe-b2ae-4e75-979d-7dea1a432855.jpeg",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "hearts": [
          "5e723c75e4bfdf4f58c55e32"
        ],
        "_id": "5e6bc41f5915e3d2980a5174",
        "email": "marc@marc.com",
        "name": "Marc",
        "photo": "4caa7bfb-6408-4893-a78b-fa6e8e5b03e7.png",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
```

```
// Second array : I iterate over "author.hearts" object 
// Called in PUG : - const store

    [{
        "product": {
            "categories": [
                1,
                2
            ]
        },
        "_id": "5e6bcc76c4022eae00e22af6",
        "date": "2222-02-20T21:22:00.000Z",
        "author": {
            "hearts": [
                "5e723c75e4bfdf4f58c55e32",
                "5e70c63a94b27b164c9b897f"
            ],
            "_id": "5e6bb1189978fd5afc98c57a",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "created": "2020-03-13T18:09:58.086Z",
        "id": "5e6bcc76c4022eae00e22af6"
    }]
```

I want to loop over the first array, find the first ID (here 5e70c63a94b27b164c9b897f), loop over the second array and see if this ID is present within the "author.hearts" object. If it is not, carry on with the second ID and if it is present, display all the keys (tags, photos, _id, date...) from the object where the ID was found.

In my example, I have just one object in my array, but I'll be having much more later on. 
Many thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself before asking?

Comment: This sort of logic is better kept out of the pug template and pre-processed in the express route.  I also agree with Sean that you need to post an attempt at solving this first, per community guidelines.

Comment: Yes @Sean, I have tried it before, since I'm doing all that mainly for training as I'm learning PUG with nodejs. I've erased what I did but I was trying things like each : 

`each val in hearts
    each obj in userHearts
        - if(val ==obj)
            .....`

And @Graham, yes I'll be later on have it running in one of my controllers. But for now, I need it processing in PUG

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly you can do something like this. Loop through all your users and when you find their id in `author.hearts` **stop** the loop there and return the object the user's `_id` was found in.

```
var resultFound = undefined;
try {
    user.forEach((el) => {
       const id = el._id;
       const result = store.find(el => el.author.hearts.includes(id));   
       if (result) {
          resultFound = result;
          throw resultFound;
       }
    });
} catch (e) {
    if (e !== resultFound) {
       throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, @haron68, I have tried what you've proposed but I couldn't access to store.author.hearts values. I might need to do an array.map here.

I have tried the following (just to check if I can get anything) :

Comment: `
- const authorHearts = store.map(count=> count.author.hearts);

- user.forEach(function(el) {
            - const id = el.hearts; // not _id because I need to compare `hearts` from "user" with author.hearts from "store"
            - const result = authorHearts.find(el => el.includes(id)); 
            - if (result == id) {
                pre=h.dump('it works') // equivalent of console.log
            - }  
        - })`

Comment: pre=h.dump(authorHearts) gives me the following array :

[
  [
    "5e70c63a94b27b164c9b897f",
    "5e723c75e4bfdf4f58c55e32"
  ],
  [
    "5e723c75e4bfdf4f58c55e32"
  ],
  [
    "5e6bcc76c4022eae00e22af6"
  ]
]
And pre=h.dump(id) gives me the following arrays :

[
  "5e70c63a94b27b164c9b897f",
  "5e723c75e4bfdf4f58c55e32"
]
[
  "5e723c75e4bfdf4f58c55e32"
]
[
  "5e6bcc76c4022eae00e22af6"
]

arrays (id).

Comment: I'm wondering if it's because I'm trying to compare values inside arrays of array (authorHearts) with values inside multiple arrays (id).

I'm very stuck with this issue :/ Many thanks

Comment: Ps : Sorry, I had an answer formated but stackoverflow deleted it, forcing me to use the comment section where it is not possible to use code formating....